Visual Studio 22 tries to execute Post build events as a single cmd

I upgradeded a Project to vs22/.net6 and it seems like vs22 is trying to execute my post-build event as a single command.
Every line is a separate xcopy cmd.
Whats the issue here?
I tried to execute in a separate batch file with same result.
In the image you can see post build event settings/outpiut.

Looks like your $(TargetDir) returns an empty string. Could you print $(TargetDir) to verify if it is parsed well?

This doc xcopy says

Eorr code 4: Initialization error occurred. There isn't enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.

Looks like some invalid  syntax on your command line. I copied your script and run it in VS2022(17.11.5) and it works well.
xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.dllp $(TargetDir)dist\bin\
xcopy /Y $(TargetDir)*.exe $(TargetDir)dist\bin\
xxx xxx

Test result

Comparing with your screenshot, it seems like that your $(TargetDir) returns an empty string. It is not replaced with correct path.
Here are suggestions to troubleshoot:

Run the following command to check if you have .NET6 SDK.

dotnet --info


Replace $(TargetDir) with a absolute full path.(e.g: C:\Users\source\repos\Project\bin\Debug\net8.0)

Add a target to print $(TargetDir) to see if the macros can be parsed well.


<Target Name="tet">
    <Message Text="TargetDir: $(TargetDir)" Importance="high" />
</Target>


Update VS2022 to the latest version.(17.11.5 is available)

Create a new project targets to .NET6 and run the scripts to see if works.



Another suggestion: Replace $(TargetDir) with $(OutputPath).
